# Scraping data in columns with no period

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab just the Symbol column excluding any symbols with a period in them ([website here](https://stockcharts.com/def/servlet/SC.scan?s=I.Y%7CTSAL%5Bt.t_eq_s%5D!%5Bas0,20,tv_gt_40000%5D!%5Bwr_eq_1%5D&report=predefalli)). So far I can scrape the page and get the entire html into a variable, however I am struggling to extract just the symbols with no period. Here's the code:

```
import bs4
import requests
import re

url = 'https://stockcharts.com/def/servlet/SC.scan?s=I.Y|TSAL[t.t_eq_s]![as0,20,tv_gt_40000]! 
[wr_eq_1]&report=predefalli' #base url to get the pages count
requests.sessions = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=requests.sessions)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')


for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'icon icon-square icon-scc-pos-sq-sharp'}):
  for link in item.find_all('a'):
         print link.get('href')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}

url = "https://stockcharts.com/def/servlet/SC.scan?s=I.Y%7CTSAL%5Bt.t_eq_s%5D!%5Bas0,20,tv_gt_40000%5D!%5Bwr_eq_1%5D&report=predefalli"

t = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
df = pd.read_html(StringIO(t))[0]

# filter-out symbols with dot (.)
df.pop("Unnamed: 0")
print(df[~df["Symbol"].str.contains(r"\.")])
```

Prints:

```
    Symbol                                                                              Name Exchange                  Sector                     Industry  SCTR    U    Close     Volume
1       AB                                                      AllianceBernstein Holding LP     NYSE               Financial               Asset Managers  92.9  mid   49.918     111285
2      ABG                                                      Asbury Automotive Group Inc.     NYSE  Consumer Discretionary          Specialty Retailers  75.8  mid  196.210      47977
3      ABR                                                           Arbor Realty Trust Inc.     NYSE             Real Estate               Mortgage REITs  79.9  mid   18.400     456439
4      ACA                                                                      Arcosa, Inc.     NYSE              Industrial          Commercial Vehicles  15.3  mid   51.980      52470
6      ACH                                                           Aluminum Corp. of China     NYSE               Materials                     Aluminum  96.8  mid   14.830      22646

...
```